# Adding ng-model to ui-date breaks datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui

html

```
<input ui-date ng-model="tDate">
```

controller

```
$scope.tDate = new Date();
$scope.$watch('tDate', function () {
                console.log($scope.tDate);
            }, true);
```

By adding the ng-model tag, the datepicker is shown on pageload which it normally shouldn't. Anyone got a lead why this happens when adding ng-model tag?

Comment: Maybe the datepicker is listening to input's onchange?

Comment: Could be. Is there any way of disabling onChangeEvent for e certain element when the page loads?

Comment: I am using this with Angular 1.1.4, Angular-UI 0.4.0 and it works OK. My difference is that I have included the `ui-date-format` attribute. The value in the model is a string formatted like "2013-09-17T21:00:00.000Z".

Comment: may or may not be a bug, but used this: http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2011/08/10/jquery-ui-datepicker-visible-upon-first-time-page-load.aspx